# Setting 'business name' and 'cancel and return' attributes on paypal review information page

Tags: email, paypal, express, checkout

We are having an issue with setting out 'business name' and the 'cancel and return' to our website link on the PAYPAL 'Review your information' page.

Can anyone advise on how we can change the details we show for these parameters? For some reason, the details are showing as a very old email address we had attached to the paypal account when we first signed up and we cannot find out how we can change it.

We have checked the details are showing correctly in our paypal profile for both our business trading name and the option is ticked and the correct website URL is included to return customers to our website in the 'cancel and return' situation.

Are the attributes controlled by our paypal profile feeds or are changes need to the coding on our shopping cart end?

We are using ubercart and paypal express checkout.

We are posting this on behalf of our website developers as we cannot get an answer from them how to change these details.

Any help will be great, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you provide a screenshot of where specifically you are seeing this show up at on the checkout page?  The Return URL, Cancel URL and business name for Express Checkout gets set in your code on your site.  You would be setting it in the SetExpressCheckout API call, you would need to modify these URL's in your code.

If you are using NVP, the variables that you would want to be looking for in your SetExpressCheckout code are as follows:

BRANDNAME - A label that overrides the business name in the PayPal account on the
PayPal hosted checkout pages.

RETURNURL - URL to which the buyer’s browser is returned after choosing to pay with
PayPal. For digital goods, you must add JavaScript to this page to close the in-context
experience.

CANCELURL - URL to which the buyer is returned if the buyer does not approve the use
of PayPal to pay you. For digital goods, you must add JavaScript to this page to close
the in-context experience.

If you have any type of logging built into your site/shopping cart you should be able to capture the request and verify what you are sending over.

Comment: Hi Unfortunately I cannot add a screenshot on here. Thanks so much for your advice, I will send the details on to our developpers and get them to check the BRANDNAME and CANCELURL specifically.  once again thanks

Comment: I am using 
<input type='hidden' name='business' value='brijkishorrajputxxx@gmail.com'>

and on paypal site is showing this email address but I want on  Name will be display not email address on paypal page

Answer (score 0):

If you're using to older forms method (now Express Checkout):

```
<input type="hidden" name="cbt"   value="YOUR_COMPANY_NAME" />
```